# Getting error while creating DataSet in SpagoBI Studio

Tags: jar, birt, spagobi, eclipse-classpath

[image]

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/mozilla/javascript/ScriptOrFnNode;
>       at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.expression.AbstractExpressionCompiler.parse(AbstractExpressionCompiler.java:238)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.expression.AbstractExpressionCompiler.compileExpression(AbstractExpressionCompiler.java:132)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.expression.ExpressionCompiler.compile(ExpressionCompiler.java:68)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.expression.ExpressionCompilerUtil.compile(ExpressionCompilerUtil.java:56)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ServiceForQueryResults.initAutoBinding(ServiceForQueryResults.java:1014)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryResults.getResultIterator(QueryResults.java:174)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ExtractionResults.nextResultIterator(ExtractionResults.java:157)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.DataSetPreviewer.preview(DataSetPreviewer.java:69)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.ResultSetPreviewPage$5.run(ResultSetPreviewPage.java:366)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)

Getting this error while creating Dataset in Studio.

I added

1. rhino 1.7.7.1 jar,
2. updated the mysql-connector jar with the latest one.
3. Added jars in the project still am getting this error.

***Please give some solution as soon as possible.***

Answer (score 0):

I searched over the internet and found that now BIRT plugins are removed from the eclipse market place so many dependency which is required for BIRT is not available even after adding SpagoBI plugins.

I downloaded "**eclipse-reporting-mars-2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar**" for mac OS from

> http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-and-report-developers/mars2

You can easily download the eclipse for Windows,Mac or Linux OS from DOWNLOAD LINK provided in the right side.

In this IDE, Reports jars are present so you will not face any issue while creating the report or cockpit.

You just need to add the SpagoBI studio plugins in Eclipse plugin folder after that it will work without any error.

Thanks, Hope this will help.